# Is there a way to change the color of the objects per unit depth when seen through the camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, depth

I am trying to change the colours of the objects in a way that they appear to be red when near to the screen and violet for the further object/point from the screen.

I have tried to implement a code for fragment part of the shader in the Unity3D but it is not working.

```
        fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET{
            //get depth from depth texture
            float depth = tex2D(_CameraDepthTexture, i.uv).r;
            //linear depth between camera and far clipping plane
            depth = Linear01Depth(depth);
            //depth as distance from camera in units 
            depth = depth * _ProjectionParams.z;

            //get source color
            fixed4 source = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

            if(depth >= _ProjectionParams.z)
                return RGB(violet);
            else
                return RGB_value_of_object_according_to_the_depth;
        }
```

Here I can get the colour of the source, but I can't change the colour of the object to the colour red if it is nearest to the camera and violet if it is furthest.

To be precise I can't fix the code for the if/else condition.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Code Credits: the code used from Ronja's exercise tutorials

Comment: that can't even compile.. go check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-vector ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-lerp

Comment: I have done that but the only problem I am facing is a smooth transition from one colour to another colour